# How-to workaround differences with Uri and encoded URLs in .Net4.0 vs .Net4.5 using HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, dotnet-httpclient

`Uri` behaves differently in .Net4.0 vs .Net4.5

```
var u = new Uri("http://localhost:5984/mycouchtests_pri/test%2F1");
Console.WriteLine(u.OriginalString);
Console.WriteLine(u.AbsoluteUri);
```

**Outcome NET4.0**

```
http://localhost:5984/mycouchtests_pri/test%2F1
http://localhost:5984/mycouchtests_pri/test/1
```

**Outcome NET4.5**

```
http://localhost:5984/mycouchtests_pri/test%2F1
http://localhost:5984/mycouchtests_pri/test%2F1
```

So when using the `HttpClient` [distributed by Microsoft via NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) requests like the above fail with .Net4.0, since the `HttpRequestMessage` is using the `Uri`.

Any ideas for a workaround?

**EDIT**
There is **a NON APPLICABLE** workaround by adding configuration for `<uri>` in e.g. `App.config` or `Machine.config` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee656539(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
<configuration>
  <uri>
    <schemeSettings>
      <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes"/>
    </schemeSettings>
  </uri>
</configuration>
```

But as this is a tools library, that's not really an option. If the `HttpClient` for .Net4.0 is supposed to be on par with the one in .Net4.5, they should have the same behavior.

Comment: You can see that `u.OriginalString` gives same values , regardless of .net frameword, So you can use that only, unless you actually need the other, Correct me if i am wrong!

Comment: I'm not in control. The URI is consumed somewhere in the dark lands of HttpClient and associated message handler.

Comment: I thought, you are concerned about using `OriginalString` vs `AbsoluteUri`! , But still i am not clear, for that you need workaround!

Comment: My concerns are to be able to pass in an `Uri` with the above URL to the `HttpRequestMessage`. I noticed that it has different behavior between .Net4.0 and 4.5 hence I started to dig around and found the above and guessing they pick something different in the two implementations - http://danielwertheim.se/2014/10/11/uri-behaves-differently-in-net4-0-vs-net4-5/

Answer (score 1):

Mike Hadlow wrote [a blog post on this](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/how-to-stop-systemuri-un-escaping.html) a few years back. Here's the code he came up with to get round this:

```
private void LeaveDotsAndSlashesEscaped()
{
    var getSyntaxMethod = 
        typeof (UriParser).GetMethod("GetSyntax", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (getSyntaxMethod == null)
    {
        throw new MissingMethodException("UriParser", "GetSyntax");
    }

    var uriParser = getSyntaxMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { "http" });

    var setUpdatableFlagsMethod = 
        uriParser.GetType().GetMethod("SetUpdatableFlags", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (setUpdatableFlagsMethod == null)
    {
        throw new MissingMethodException("UriParser", "SetUpdatableFlags");
    }

    setUpdatableFlagsMethod.Invoke(uriParser, new object[] {0});
}
```

I think it just sets the flag that's available from `.config` in code, so while it's hacky, it's not exactly unsupported.

Comment: That suffers from the same problem as the config file: it modifies the setting for the entire AppDomain.

Comment: Thanks, did stumble upon this elsewhere. Also a workaround, but I do not want to call that, in that case consumer would have to do it in bootstrap mode or something, this since it potentially "affects"  other running libs in the same domain.