# Uri.AbsoluteUri vs. Uri.OriginalString

Tags: c#, .net, uri, url-encoding

I recently became aware of the odd behavior of `Uri.ToString()` (namely, it unencodes some characters and therefore is primarily suitable for display purposes). I'm trying to decide between `AbsoluteUri` and `OriginalString` as my "go-to" for converting a `Uri` object to a string (e. g. in a razor view).

So far, the only difference I've found between the two is that `AbsoluteUri` will fail for relative uris (e. g. `new Uri("foo", UriKind.Relative).AbsoluteUri`). That seems like a point in favor of `OriginalString`. However, I'm concerned by the word "original", since it suggests that maybe some things will not get properly encoded or escaped.

Can anyone confirm the difference between these two properties (aside from the one difference I found)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normalization is a good reason to use `AbsoluteUri` over `OriginalString`:

```
new Uri("http://foo.bar/var/../gar").AbsoluteUri // http://foo.bar/gar
new Uri("http://foo.bar/var/../gar").OriginalString // http://foo.bar/var/../gar
```

Comment: Is the normalization part of API definition?

Comment: @Xolve are you asking about whether Uri is documented to return normalized (canonical) value (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-6.0#remarks) or what [Uri normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_normalization) is?

Answer (score 12):

I always favor `OriginalString` as I've ran into multiple issues with `AbsoluteUri`. Namely:

### AbsoluteUri behaves differently in .NET 4.0 vs .NET 4.5 ([see](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26315934))

#### .NET Framework 4.0

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/test%2F1");

Console.WriteLine(uri.OriginalString);
// http://www.example.com/test%2F1

Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsoluteUri);
// http://www.example.com/test/1  <--  WRONG
```

#### .NET Framework 4.5

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/test%2F1");

Console.WriteLine(uri.OriginalString);
// http://www.example.com/test%2F1

Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsoluteUri);
// http://www.example.com/test%2F1
```

### AbsoluteUri doesn't support relative URIs

```
var uri = new Uri("/test.aspx?v=hello world", UriKind.Relative);

Console.WriteLine(uri.OriginalString);
// /test.aspx?v=hello world

Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsoluteUri);
// InvalidOperationException: This operation is not supported for a relative URI.
```

### AbsoluteUri does unwanted escaping

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/test.aspx?v=hello world");

Console.WriteLine(uri.OriginalString);
// http://www.example.com/test.aspx?v=hello world

Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsoluteUri);
// http://www.example.com/test.aspx?v=hello%20world  <--  WRONG
```

Comment: Regarding the last point, `http://www.example.com/test.aspx?v=hello%20world` is a valid URL, as spaces must be escape. OriginalString gives invalid URL suitable for viewing only

Comment: I didn't say it's invalid; I said it's _wrong_, at least in the context of this question. I intentionally used and invalid URL to highlight the difference; the author talks about Uri.ToString() decoding some characters. AbsoluteUri suffers from this also, except it _encodes_ some characters. If you want the original, __unaltered__ URL (as in… the one used to instantiate the Uri object at hand, no encoding, no decoding), `OriginalString` provides just that. If this URL is invalid, I'd much rather find out how it got there in the first place and not have AbsoluteUri cover it up.

Comment: "http://www.example.com/test%2F1" doesnn't look like a valid url, expect query params to be encoded only. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: `example.com/test%2F1` does not contain any invalid characters so it _is_ a valid URL. Although the query string is the most common usage, URL encoding is not limited to it. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding), _percent-encoding is a mechanism to encode 8-bit characters that have specific meaning **in the context of URLs**_.

Answer (score 0):

For converting a Uri object to a string I was using

```
Location.ToString().StripQuotes();
```

Note that ToString generated url string wrapped with double quotes ", and I had to remove them using StripQuotes from [Flurl/src/Flurl/Util/CommonExtensions.cs](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/blob/129565361e135e639f1d44a35a78aea4302ac6ca/src/Flurl/Util/CommonExtensions.cs)

See also [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.tostring.aspx) that illustrates the difference between the value returned from OriginalString, which returns the string that was passed to the constructor, and from a call to ToString, which returns the canonical form of the string.